# How can I log source of mouse input?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, touchscreen, logging, xinput

For some reason mouse pointer sometimes teleports to the top of the screen and starts repeatedly clicking.

Is there some easy way to record mouse inputs and their source? I am aware of `xinput list` and tried already

```
xinput set-prop 15 "Device Enabled" 0 # touchscreen
xinput set-prop 16 "Device Enabled" 0 # "DLL07A0:01 044E:120B" - confirmed to be touchpad
xinput set-prop 17 "Device Enabled" 0 # DualPoint Stick
```

to disable touchscreen and touchpad and stick between GHB keyboards keys, what seems to help with seizures. But I want to track down what exactly is broken.

Comment: Certainly sounds like the mouse is broken. Boot from live media and see if it does the same or try another mouse.

Comment: @David Mouse is not a problem, this happens when all devices are detached from laptop. So problem is in software or in hardware - I hope that is not motherboard issue but rather one of laptop input devices.

Comment: For live media - it is not happening all the time so it is tricky to judge has problem disappeared or not.

Comment: From your question. this happens when all devices are detached from laptop The question only talks about the mouse. Suggest you update the question with the edit command and explain what this means and any other info you need to add.

Comment: Or there is another mouse of the same brand using the same channel.

Comment: For now I selectively disabled on start: and it is touchscreen that is broken, or at least disabling input from it fixes everything